# Prevent flex items from occupying leftover width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a set of images as tiles with the following css properties:
For the parent

```
.poster-container > div {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction:row;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
```

and for the flexed items:

```
.poster-item {
                flex: 1 0 10%;
                margin: 30px;
                height: auto;
                text-align:center;
                overflow: hidden;
                position:relative;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
```

I have restricted it such that at most 6 tiles can appear in a row. However, when there are less than 6 tiles in the last row, the flexed items stretch out to take equal width each. How can i restrict the tiles from stretching across the whole width so that they are displayed as tiles in the other rows?

Answer (score 0):

`flex: 1 0 10%;` this means grow, don't shrink, and have a basis of 10%. See the explanation here and you will also find an example that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set `flex-grow: 0` in order not to grow, so `flex: 0 0 16.666667%` (100/6 %)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 30px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```